# warning message glmer Model failed to converge

Tags: r, warnings, lme4

I have seen questions about this on this forum (and have asked it myself before) but I haven't been able to solve my problem still, so I wil try again with more detailed information:

I have a data set with a binomial dependent variable, 3 categorical fixed effects and 2 categorical random effects (item and subject). I want to to a mixed effects model using glmer. Here is what I entered in R:

```
modelall<- glmer(moodR ~ group*context*condition + (1|subject) + ``(1|item), data=RprodHSNS, family="binomial")`
```

I then get the following warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.02081 (tol = 0.001, component 11)
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
- Rescale variables?`
```

This is what my summary looks like:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: moodR ~ group * context * condition + (1 | subject) + (1 | item)
Data: RprodHSNS`


AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid
1400.0   1479.8   -686.0   1372.0     2195 `

Scaled residuals: 
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-8.0346 -0.2827 -0.0152  0.2038 20.6578 `

Random effects:
Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev.
item    (Intercept) 1.475    1.215   
subject (Intercept) 1.900    1.378   
Number of obs: 2209, groups:  item, 54; subject, 45
Fixed effects:`
Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)`                             
(Intercept)                -0.61448   42.93639  -0.014 0.988582  
group1                     -1.29254   42.93612  -0.030 0.975984    
context1                    0.09359   42.93587   0.002 0.998261   
context2                   -0.77262    0.22894  -3.375 0.000739***
condition1                  4.99219   46.32672   0.108 0.914186
group1:context1            -0.17781   42.93585  -0.004 0.996696
group1:context2            -0.10551    0.09925  -1.063 0.287741
group1:condition1          -3.07516   46.32653  -0.066 0.947075
context1:condition1        -3.47541   46.32648  -0.075 0.940199
context2:condition1        -0.07293    0.22802  -0.320 0.749087
group1:context1:condition1  2.47882   46.32656   0.054 0.957328
group1:context2:condition1  0.30360    0.09900   3.067 0.002165 **

---

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) group1 cntxt1 cntxt2 cndtn1 grp1:cnt1 grp1:2 grp1:cnd1 cnt1:1 cnt2:1 g1:1:1
group1      -1.000                                                                            
context1    -1.000  1.000                                                                
context2     0.001  0.000 -0.001                                                              
condition1  -0.297  0.297  0.297  0.000                                                       
grp1:cntxt1  1.000 -1.000 -1.000  0.001 -0.297                                                
grp1:cntxt2  0.001  0.000  0.000 -0.123  0.000  0.000                                       
grp1:cndtn1  0.297 -0.297 -0.297 -0.001 -1.000  0.297     0.000                               
cntxt1:cnd1  0.297 -0.297 -0.297 -0.001 -1.000  0.297     0.001  1.000                        
cntxt2:cnd1  0.000  0.000 -0.001  0.011  0.001  0.000    -0.197 -0.001    -0.001              
grp1:cnt1:1 -0.297  0.297  0.297  0.001  1.000 -0.297    -0.001 -1.000    -1.000  0.001       
grp1:cnt2:1  0.000  0.000  0.001 -0.198  0.000 -0.001     0.252  0.000     0.001 -0.136  0.000
```

Extremely high p-values, which does not seem to be possible.

In a previous post I read that one of the problems could be fixed by increasing the amount of iterations by inserting this bit in the command: glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000))

So here's the new command:

```
modelall<- glmer(moodR ~ group*context*condition + (1|subject) + (1|item), data=RprodHSNS, family="binomial", glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000)))
```

I get one less warning, but the other one is still there:

```
> Warning message:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.005384 (tol = 0.001, component 7)
```

The summary still looks weird:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: moodR ~ group * context * condition + (1 | subject) + (1 | item)
   Data: RprodHSNS
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e+05))`

AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
1400.0   1479.8   -686.0   1372.0     2195

Scaled residuals: 
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-8.0334 -0.2827 -0.0152  0.2038 20.6610 

Random effects:
Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev.
item    (Intercept) 1.474    1.214   
subject (Intercept) 1.901    1.379   
Number of obs: 2209, groups:  item, 54; subject, 45

Fixed effects:
                        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                -0.64869   26.29368  -0.025 0.980317    
group1                     -1.25835   26.29352  -0.048 0.961830    
context1                    0.12772   26.29316   0.005 0.996124    
context2                   -0.77265    0.22886  -3.376 0.000735 ***
condition1                  4.97325   22.80050   0.218 0.827335    
group1:context1            -0.21198   26.29303  -0.008 0.993567    
group1:context2            -0.10552    0.09924  -1.063 0.287681    
group1:condition1          -3.05629   22.80004  -0.134 0.893365    
context1:condition1        -3.45656   22.80017  -0.152 0.879500    
context2:condition1        -0.07305    0.22794  -0.320 0.748612    
group1:context1:condition1  2.45996   22.80001   0.108 0.914081    
group1:context2:condition1  0.30347    0.09899   3.066 0.002172 ** 

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
        (Intr) group1 cntxt1 cntxt2 cndtn1 grp1:cnt1 grp1:2 grp1:cnd1 cnt1:1 cnt2:1 g1:1:1
group1      -1.000                                                                            
context1    -1.000  1.000                                                                     
context2     0.000  0.000  0.000                                                              
condition1   0.123 -0.123 -0.123 -0.001                                                       
grp1:cntxt1  1.000 -1.000 -1.000  0.001  0.123                                                
grp1:cntxt2  0.001  0.000  0.000 -0.123  0.001  0.000                                         
grp1:cndtn1 -0.123  0.123  0.123  0.000 -1.000 -0.123    -0.001                               
cntxt1:cnd1 -0.123  0.123  0.123  0.000 -1.000 -0.123     0.000  1.000                        
cntxt2:cnd1  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.011 -0.001  0.000    -0.197  0.001     0.001              
grp1:cnt1:1  0.123 -0.123 -0.123  0.000  1.000  0.123     0.000 -1.000    -1.000 -0.001      
grp1:cnt2:1  0.000 -0.001  0.001 -0.198  0.001 -0.001     0.252 -0.001     0.000 -0.136  0.000
```

> 

Does anyone have an idea what I can do to solve this? Or tell me what this warning even means? Please explain in a way that an R-newbie like myself can understand!

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you followed the advice in `help("convergence")`?

Comment: First a warning: general linear mixed effects models can fail a lot, often when the estimated standard errors are really small for example and it's really annoying. That being said, looking at your correlations of fixed effects, note that a lot of them are perfectly correlated. Are you sure that your covariate matrix is full rank?

Comment: Thanks for you replies. The help("convergence") command did not make things any clearer for me unfortunately. And I'm afraid I am too much of a statistics beginner to understand what full rank means and what it means that fixed effects are perfectly correlated. You mean when the correlation is 1, I suppose? So between context1 and group1 for example. I have no idea why there would be a perfect correlation there, it doesn't make sense given my data set. Can it not be the case that the numbers for correlation effects are not reliable either, due to the warning?